# How to parse individual likes from FQL query response?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am using FQL to find the likes of a user. It is returning all the likes as CSV. For example, this the response for my likes:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [uid] => XXXXXXX [name] => XXXXXXX [movies] => Pi, 12 Angry Men, The Shining, Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels ) )
```

I tried using php's explode at comma to parse the individual movie names but that leads to an error.
Over here, the last movie I like is "Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels" which has a comma in its name. So, how do I parse this movie name? I can't split at comma, because then I will get two movies - "Lock" ; "Stock and Two Smoking Barrels".